# Creating an echo-server: Connected client gets IO-exception

Tags: java, chat, inputstream, outputstream, printwriter

I'm trying to create a single-threaded echo-server, but I can't figure out how to send the input from the client back to the client again from the server. The client connects to the server alright, but it's when it's waiting for a response that it throws an IOException. I have tried connecting my chat client to other chat servers, hence I'm sure the fault is in the chat server implementation.

I'm guessing the "villain of the piece" is this method presented below that takes the input from the connected client and sends it back, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

```
private void processClientRequest(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    PrintWriter out = 
        new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    out.write("Server - " + time + ": " + in);

    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

Please tell me if this method isn't the issue and you need other parts of my code instead.
Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have now managed to get my server to respond to the client. I did this by changing the processClientRequest method to this:

```
try {
    BufferedReader in =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    PrintWriter out = 
        new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    out.write("Server - " + time + ": " + in.readLine());

    out.close();

    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't close input stream");
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Got an IOException error while reading or writing from/to client");
}
```

But as of now my server can only respond the client once. If the client writes to the server a second time it does get a response, but instead of the clients message, it's "null". And since I want my echo server to be able to answer the client until the client shuts down or something like that, I need to figure out how to change that. I figure I'm going to need some kind of while loop to make this happen, but I have tried for example putting the whole try statement into an infinite while loop, but that just gave me loads of IOExceptions.

Comment: Since I'm quite new to stackoverflow I need to ask: Can I ask a follow up question like I did now with my edit, or do I need to create an entirely new thread?

Comment: If your first question has been answered, mark the accepted answer accordingly and ask a new one. You can link to the first question for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not reading the clients input. You're just passing the `toString` to your out. You need to make a while loop and read from in. Maybe in a seperate thread unless you're sure the input is short. In test code should be okay:

```
    private void processClientRequest(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();//wrap this in a object stream or other to read lines/ utf
        int i = 0;
        while(i++ < 1000 && in.available() > 0){
          int read = in.read();//use it if u want, like to a string builder declared out of loop and echo it back after u read input
         }
        PrintWriter out = 
        new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        out.write("Server - " + time + ": " + in);

        out.close();//should be in seperate try catches so if 1 close fails u still close other and finally close socket in 3rd try catch
        in.close();
}
```

[Socket server](http://www.quickserver.org/) with working echo server, mini web server and helpful in many more ways.

Comment: Thanks! Wrapping my InputStream in a BufferedReader as the comment suggested helped me understand how I could read the input from the client. I changed the InputStream line to this:
    "BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));"

And the out.write() line to this:
    "out.write("Server - " + time + ": " + in.readLine());"

But sadly I don't understand how to use the while loop you suggested and how it would work. As of now I'm able to send a response back to the client, but only once. And I guess that's what your loop is supposed to solve.

Comment: Sorry my comment got too long, just had to add that I tried your while loop and I couldn't get it to work. And even if it worked I would have no idea why. Why read from the InputStream and then put the result in an Integer (why Integer?) that is never used? So if you could explain how your suggested while loop works or how I should do something similar with my "new solution", I would be very grateful! :)

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka [InputStream#read()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--) return `the next byte of data from the input stream that is a value in the range [0, 255]`. In order to implement an echo server you need to read what clients send to the server and  send it back to them i.e. write to the OutpurStream of the client socket. The client needs than to read the server's answer which ist exactly the same he as what he sent.

Comment: @A4L I know what the method does, but I don't get why I would want to put the answer into a variable that I never use. I've managed to implement an almost functioning echo server, as you can see if you check out the new edit of my question. So now my echo server works, but it can only respond once, which is what I need to change now.

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka in your code you do `out.write("Server - " + time + ": " + in.readLine());`. The statement `in.readLine()` returns a value which you use to send back to the client. So your statement `put the answer into a variable that I never use` is not true.

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka As for your second question in the comment, the echo server responds only once to a single client request, so what you are seeing is correct. If you want to have the server respond mutliple times, then you have to send mutiple requests/messages, you could do this in a while loop in your client, or just simply execute your client mutiple time, for example from commad line, each time passing a different message as command line argument.

Comment: @A4L Oh just a misunderstanding. I meant that inside the while loop the value of "in.readLine()" gets put into the variable "int read", which is never used, right?

And actually, my client application is able to send and receive multiple requests/messages while being connected to other servers, so I guess that means that the problem lies within the server? Or does that only mean that they are using another method for response than my server is which works better with my client application?

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka Your server should, after getting the client socket via accept, call the method which takes it as parameter, and where you have the code you have shown in your question. Usually this is done in new thread so that the server can handle mutiple client request asynchronously. So the pattern is: `while(! serverStopped) { clientSocket =  serverSocket.accept(); new Thread(new MyClientHandler(clientSocket)).start(); }` where `class MyClientHandler implements Runnable { ... }`

Comment: Thanks! Actually I already have this "ClientHandler class", and the "ProcessClientRequest" method is now removed and the code that I've shown in my question is placed in the the run()-method of that ClientHandler. It was a change I did during the course of this day. And my chat server has the pattern you presented. The problem still remains the same though. I can only get one proper response from the server. After that the server still answers, but not with the clients input, but with "null" instead.

Comment: http://www.quickserver.org/ can take a look at this open source prodution ready (its actively used in 7 production systems that i know of since 2008)